# Saving and Closing a file with a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, tableau-api

So I'm using a sweet .bat file to open a tableau desktop workbook update dashboard with server data, and logout. Set with task scheduler, It executes the every day, and I'm happy with it, but It has the unfortunate consequence of leaving the file open and unsaved. So, how do I:

1. Save the file (.twbx)
2. And then close file

Thanks!

Comment: Unless Tableau Desktop has a command line version, batch can't do this.

Comment: It does. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#extracting_TDE.html

Comment: @SomethingDark  I fail to see how this is off topic. I've seen no less than a dozen stacks posing the exact same question, but tagged for Excel. Now, Excel has its own commands for this (which I have done limitedly in the past), Tableau has its own command-line version, however I don't see a specific command to save or close. In this case, would you use SET?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to publish your data separately from your workbook. In that case you can publish data updates with the tableau data extract command line utility (on windows) https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#extracting_TDE.html. Or via the REST API.

Even simpler, put your data in database with a live connection and it will always be up to date

If you must update your workbook itself, there is a document API on GitHub

Comment: Thanks @alex-blakemore , appreciate your comment. In this case, I do have to update the workbook itself. this is what I have so far: 'tableau tabcmd login -s Servername.DBNAME refreshextracts  --synchronous --workbook "FILEPATH"
tabcmd logout
exit /b` So, it appears to refresh just fine, but how would I go about the save/close portion?

Comment: If all you are doing is refreshing the extract as your command line shows, then you *don't* have to modify the workbook -- if you first separate the extract from the workbook by publishing the data source